# How do we get all the users who are part of public group of current logged in user?

Tags: user-record, public-group

I want get a list of all the users who are part of public group  of the currently logged in user.

From what i have read on the documentations, i should be able to pick these values from group and group member objects.

Things begin to get messier while using [group member](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api/Content/sforce_api_objects_groupmember.htm) object. I cant really in a sure shot way say a user is part of group

> Usage
>
> A record exists for every User or Group who is a direct member of a
>   public group whose Type field is set to Regular. User records that are
>   indirect members of Regular public groups are not listed as group
>   members. A User can be an indirect member of a group if he or she is
>   in a UserRole above the direct group member in the hierarchy, or if he
>   or she is a member of a group that is included as a subgroup in that
>   group.

Can anyone point me towards a best way of getting this list?

Answer (score 5):

From my experience, accessing direct group members isn't too bad - you just iterate the group and for all user members just pull their details.  If it is a group member, you just recursively call your function that iterates the group.

Where things get really sticky is when you try to figure out the indirect members - I've found that when you start trying to traverse the role hierarchy on a user by user basis, unless you have a flat structure you very quickly run out of SOQL queries.

Here's an example of traversing a group and subgroups to get all user ids:

```
    public static Set<id> GetUserIdsFromGroup(Id groupId)
    {
        // store the results in a set so we don't get duplicates
        Set<Id> result=new Set<Id>();
        String userType = Schema.SObjectType.User.getKeyPrefix();
        String groupType = Schema.SObjectType.Group.getKeyPrefix();

        // Loop through all group members in a group
        for (GroupMember m : [Select Id, UserOrGroupId From GroupMember Where GroupId = :groupId])
        {
            // If the user or group id is a user
            if (((String)m.UserOrGroupId).startsWith(userType))
            {
                result.add(m.UserOrGroupId);
            }
            // If the user or group id is a group
            // Note: there may be a problem with governor limits if this is called too many times
            else if (((String)m.UserOrGroupId).startsWith(groupType))
            {
                // Call this function again but pass in the group found within this group
                result.addAll(GetUSerIdsFromGroup(m.UserOrGroupId));
            }
        }

        return result;  
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

I found a bug in your code. Please check it below.

```
public static Set<id> GetUserIdsFromGroup(Set<Id> groupIds)
{
    // store the results in a set so we don't get duplicates
    Set<Id> result=new Set<Id>();
    String userType = Schema.SObjectType.User.getKeyPrefix();
    String groupType = Schema.SObjectType.Group.getKeyPrefix();
    Set<Id> groupIdProxys = new Set<Id>();
    // Loop through all group members in a group
    for(GroupMember m : [Select Id, UserOrGroupId From GroupMember Where GroupId in :groupIds])
    {
        // If the user or group id is a user
        if(((String)m.UserOrGroupId).startsWith(userType))
        {
            result.add(m.UserOrGroupId);
        }
        // If the user or group id is a group
        // Note: there may be a problem with governor limits if this is called too many times
        else if (((String)m.UserOrGroupId).startsWith(groupType))
        {
            // Call this function again but pass in the group found within this group
            groupIdProxys.add(m.UserOrGroupId);
        }
    }
    if(groupIdProxys.size() > 0)
    {
        result.addAll(GetUSerIdsFromGroup(groupIdProxys));
    }
    return result;  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the Code below You have to call GetRoleVsUSerMap Method it will return all Users Id under each Group id existing in your Org.

```
public class AllPublicGroupQuery {

    public static Set<Id> grpids = new Set<Id>();
    public static Set<Id> Roleids = new Set<Id>();
    public static Map<String,Set<String>> finalmap = new Map<String,Set<String>>();  
    Public static Map<String,Set<String>> mapParentToChild = new Map<String,Set<String>>();
    public static Map<String,Set<String>> grpidTomemberid = new Map<String,Set<String>>();
    public static Map<String,Set<String>> MapgrpToRole = new Map<String,Set<String>>();
    public static Map<String,Set<String>> MapgrpToRoleSub = new Map<String,Set<String>>();
    public static Map<String,Set<String>> MapgrpToUser = new Map<String,Set<String>>();

    public static Map<String,Set<String>> GetRoleVsUSerMap(){
        Map<String,String> mapGrpRelatedids = new Map<String,String>();
        Map<Id,string> mapgrpType = new Map<Id,String>();
        Set<Id> userOrGrpids = new Set<Id>();
        Set<String> grpparentids = new Set<String>();

        for(GroupMember gpmem : [SELECT GroupId,Id,UserOrGroupId FROM GroupMember]){
            if(gpmem.UserOrGroupId != null)
                userOrGrpids.add(gpmem.UserOrGroupId);
        }
        for(Group gp:[SELECT Id,Type,RelatedId FROM Group where Id In:userOrGrpids ]){
            grpids.add(gp.Id);
            if(gp.Type != NULL)
                mapgrpType.put(gp.Id,gp.type);
            if(gp.RelatedId != NULL && (gp.Type == 'Role' || gp.Type == 'RoleAndSubordinates'))
                mapGrpRelatedids.put(gp.Id, gp.RelatedId);
        }

        for(GroupMember grpmem : [SELECT GroupId,UserOrGroupId FROM GroupMember ORDER BY GroupId DESC NULLS LAST]){

            if(grpidTomemberid.get(grpmem.GroupId) == NULL){
                Set<String> ids = new Set<String>();
                ids.add(grpmem.UserOrGroupId);
                grpidTomemberid.put(grpmem.GroupId,ids);
            }
            else{
                grpidTomemberid.get(grpmem.GroupId).add(grpmem.UserOrGroupId);
            }
        }

        for(String mapkey : grpidTomemberid.keySet()){
            for(String keyval : grpidTomemberid.get(mapkey)){
                if(mapgrpType.get(keyval) == 'Role'){
                    if(MapgrpToRole.get(mapkey) == NULL){
                        Set<String> ids = new Set<String>();
                        ids.add(mapGrpRelatedids.get(keyval));
                        MapgrpToRole.put(mapkey,ids);
                    }
                    else{
                        MapgrpToRole.get(mapkey).add(mapGrpRelatedids.get(keyval));  
                    }
                }
                else if(mapgrpType.get(keyval) == 'RoleAndSubordinates'){
                    if(MapgrpToRoleSub.get(mapkey) == NULL){
                        Set<String> ids = new Set<String>();
                        ids.add(mapGrpRelatedids.get(keyval));
                        MapgrpToRoleSub.put(mapkey,ids);
                    }
                    else{
                        MapgrpToRoleSub.get(mapkey).add(mapGrpRelatedids.get(keyval));  
                    }
                }
                else if(mapgrpType.get(keyval) == 'Regular'){
                    if(mapParentToChild.get(mapkey) == NULL){
                        Set<String> ids = new Set<String>();
                        ids.add(keyval); 
                        mapParentToChild.put(mapkey,ids);
                    }
                    else{
                       mapParentToChild.get(mapkey).add(keyval); 
                    }
                }
                else{
                    if(MapgrpToUser.get(mapkey) == NULL){
                        Set<String> ids = new Set<String>();
                        ids.add(keyval); 
                        MapgrpToUser.put(mapkey,ids);
                    }
                    else{
                       MapgrpToUser.get(mapkey).add(keyval); 
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        /***************Here we iterate Group under group ***********************/

        if(mapParentToChild != NULL && mapParentToChild.keySet().size()>0 ){
            for(String parentid : mapParentToChild.keySet()){
                for(String childid : mapParentToChild.get(parentid)){
                     if( MapgrpToRoleSub.get(childid).size()>0 && MapgrpToRole.get(childid) !=NULL){
                         if(MapgrpToRole.get(parentid) == NULL){
                            Set<String> ids = new Set<String>();
                            ids.addAll(MapgrpToRole.get(childid));
                            MapgrpToRole.put(parentid,ids);
                         }
                         else
                            MapgrpToRole.get(parentid).addAll(MapgrpToRole.get(childid));
                     }
                     if(MapgrpToRoleSub.get(childid).size()>0 && MapgrpToRoleSub.get(childid) !=NULL){
                         if(MapgrpToRoleSub.get(parentid) == NULL){
                            Set<String> ids = new Set<String>();
                            ids.addAll(MapgrpToRoleSub.get(childid));
                            MapgrpToRoleSub.put(parentid,ids);
                         }
                         else
                            MapgrpToRoleSub.get(parentid).addAll(MapgrpToRoleSub.get(childid));
                     }
                     if(MapgrpToUser.get(childid).size()>0 && MapgrpToUser.get(childid) != NULL){
                        if(MapgrpToUser.get(parentid) == NULL){
                            Set<String> ids = new Set<String>();
                            ids.addAll(MapgrpToUser.get(childid));
                            MapgrpToUser.put(parentid,ids);
                        }
                        else
                            MapgrpToUser.get(parentid).addAll(MapgrpToUser.get(childid));
                     }  
                }
            }
            queryGroupuser(MapgrpToRole,MapgrpToRoleSub,MapgrpToUser);
        }
        system.debug('----finalmap---->'+finalmap);
        return finalmap;
    }
    public Static void queryGroupuser(Map<String,Set<String>> rolemap,Map<String,Set<String>> rolesubmap,Map<String,Set<String>> usrmap){
        Map<String,List<String>> maproleAndUsr = new Map<String,List<String>>();
        Map<Id,List<Id>> copymaproleAndUsr = new Map<Id,List<Id>>();
        Map<String,Set<String>> mapSubandUsr = new Map<String,Set<String>>();

        if(rolemap.keySet().size() > 0){
            for(User usr: [SELECT UserRoleId,Id FROM User where Name != 'Chatter Expert']){
                if(maproleAndUsr.get(usr.UserRoleId) == null && usr.UserRoleId !=Null){
                   List<String> ids= new List<String>();
                   ids.add(usr.Id);
                   maproleAndUsr.put(usr.UserRoleId,ids);
                }else if(usr.UserRoleId !=Null)
                    maproleAndUsr.get(usr.UserRoleId).add(usr.Id);
            }
            for(String rolekey : rolemap.keySet()){
                for(String rolevalue : rolemap.get(rolekey)){
                    if(finalmap.get(rolekey) == NULL){
                        Set<String> ids = new Set<String>();
                        if(maproleAndUsr.get(rolevalue) != NULL && maproleAndUsr.get(rolevalue).size() > 0)
                            ids.addAll(maproleAndUsr.get(rolevalue));
                        finalmap.put(rolekey,ids);
                    } 
                    else if(maproleAndUsr.get(rolevalue) != NULL && maproleAndUsr.get(rolevalue).size() > 0)
                        finalmap.get(rolekey).addAll(maproleAndUsr.get(rolevalue));
                }
            }
        }
        if(rolesubmap.keySet().size() > 0){
            for(UserRole usr: [SELECT Id FROM UserRole order by Name]){
                RoleIds.add(Usr.Id);
            }
            copymaproleAndUsr =  AllUserRoleQuery.GetRoleVsUSerMap(RoleIds);
            for(Id key : copymaproleAndUsr.keySet()){
                Set<String> ids = new Set<String>();
                for(Id value : copymaproleAndUsr.get(key)){  
                        ids.add((String)value);
                }
                mapSubandUsr.put((String)key,ids);

            }


            for(String subrolekey : rolesubmap.keySet()){
                for(String subrolevalue : rolesubmap.get(subrolekey)){
                    if(finalmap.get(subrolekey) == NULL){
                        Set<String> ids = new Set<String>();
                        if(mapSubandUsr.get(subrolevalue) != NULL)
                            ids.addAll(mapSubandUsr.get(subrolevalue));
                        finalmap.put(subrolekey,ids);
                    } 
                    else if(mapSubandUsr.get(subrolevalue) != NULL)
                        finalmap.get(subrolekey).addAll(mapSubandUsr.get(subrolevalue));
                }
            }
        }

        if(usrmap.keySet().size() > 0){
            for(String usrkey : usrmap.keySet()){
                   if(finalmap.get(usrkey) == NULL){
                        Set<String> ids = new Set<String>();
                        if(usrmap.get(usrkey) != NULL)
                            ids.addAll(usrmap.get(usrkey));
                        finalmap.put(usrkey,ids);
                   }
                   else if(usrmap.get(usrkey) != NULL)
                       finalmap.get(usrkey).addAll(usrmap.get(usrkey));
            }
        }
    }
}
```